# Qutebrowser - defining keybinds with a one-liner (instead of config file)

Tags: command-line, browser

I'm trying to write a really simple wrapper with Qutebrowser, and I'd like to define my key binds in the same line I execute the binary; e.g. `qutebrowser --target window --set content.cookies.store false :bind <Alt-g>o hint`.

As you might know, settings for Qutebrowser are typically defined in a settings file and an input file. In the manual and commentary, I've learned that much of the former file (and all of it, for my use case) can be replaced with the argument --set OPTION VALUE. Having tested that out, it works. The latter, however, I haven't been able to make behave the way I want.

In the man page, it says you can make Qutebrowser execute commands upon start up sort of like this: `qutebrowser :command FOO BAR`. When in a Qutebrowser session, if you execute a command like :bind  hint, it works (although I'd actually like to bind hint to Alt-g o, but I can't figure out how to express that); hint is bound to Alt-g, and when I use that binding, it activates hinting mode. If I clear my settings (they persist between sessions even if they're defined interactively) and open the browser again and define that binding while invoking Qutebrowser, it doesn't have any affect.

My other problem is that I don't know how to express the key chord "Alt-g o". I'd like to have similar bindings for different hint commands that rely on the Alt-g prefix (thus, `:bind <Alt-g o> hint`, `:bind <Alt-g O> hint window`), but I need to get the previous issue, first.

Yes, I'm aware of `--basedir`. I'd rather it didn't come to this argument, because it means the wrapper isn't really portable, and I also think config files are annoying.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'd actually like to bind hint to Alt-g o, but I can't figure out how to express that

According to the help file you should be using something like:

```
: bind <Alt-G>o hint
```

> **bind**
>
> Syntax: `:bind [--mode mode] [--default] [key] [command]`
>
> Bind a key to a command.
>
> If no command is given, show the current binding for the given key.
>   Using :bind without any arguments opens a page showing all
>   keybindings. positional arguments
>
> - key: The keychain to bind. Examples of valid keychains are `gC`, `<Ctrl-X>` or `<Ctrl-C>a`.
> - command: The command to execute, with optional args.
>
> optional arguments
>
> - -m, --mode: A comma-separated list of modes to bind the key in (default: normal). See :help bindings.commands for the available
>     modes.
> - -d, --default: If given, restore a default binding.
>
> note
>
> - This command does not split arguments after the last argument and handles quotes literally.
> - With this command, ;; is interpreted literally instead of splitting off a second command.
> - This command does not replace variables like {url}.

Source [qutebrowser](https://qutebrowser.org/doc/help/commands.html#bind)